# Function strictly increasing please help

Tags: functions

Prove that $$ f(x)=x+(1/2)\cos(x) $$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: Have you tried deriving it?

Comment: I dont know-how to derivate

Comment: Then the job may be tougher than what I originaly thought. Is this some sort of homework? Because the solution is trivial once you know a few things about derivatives.

Comment: Do you know how to show that $|\cos x - \cos y| \le |x-y|$?

Comment: Nope i dont know

Comment: How about $|\sin x| \le |x|$?

Comment: What is your definition of cos?

Answer (score 1):

$f'(x) = 1-{1 \over 2} \sin x \ge {1 \over 2} $ for all $x$.

Comment: The derivative of $\cos$ is $-\sin$ however, so it is $1 -\frac12 \sin x$

Comment: @ljfa: Thanks for catching my sloppiness!

Comment: It seems that the OP does not know derivatives. So ... !

Comment: Please don't mind...but the OP said that he doesn't know derivatives yet.